# Bison: Why it accepts the rule with less characters covered?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lex

I have this piece of code:

```
QuasiQuotes: DOUBLELEFTQUOTES QuotedRules DOUBLERIGHTQUOTES { $$ = $2; };
QuotedRules: stmts {}
| lvalue {}

stmts:  stmts stmt  {...}
        |/*empty*/ {...}
        ;
stmt:   expr SEMICOLON      {...}
lvalue:     ID {...}
;
expr:   lvalue  EQUAL expr  {...}
```

and i pass the test: `<< x =5; >>;`
Now according to the rules of the Bison it will accept the rule that "covers" the most characters, in this case it would be the "stmts" but instead it seems that it accepts the lvalue where i get the error: syntax error, unexpected EQUAL, expecting DOUBLERIGHTQUOTES

I noticed that if i have `QuotedRules: stmt {} | lvalue {}` it seems to work fine and accept the rule that i want.
( so there may be a problem at stmts rule? )
I also tried changing the precedence here: %left/right/nonassoc  DOUBLELEFTQUOTES DOUBLERIGHTQUOTES, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have no rule for `expr`, so bison won't even make a working parser for this.  You need some rule that accepts an `EQUAL` in order to have any chance of making this work.  If you add `expr: INTCONST | lvalue EQUAL expr ;` it should work.

Comment: You are confused. It is *lex(1)/flex(1)* that 'accept the rule that "covers" the most characters'. Not Bison.

Comment: Yes i have rule for expr, but i didnt include the whole code as it would be confusing.

Comment: @user207421 oh yes it seems that i got confused. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Well you need to include the rule for `expr`, otherwise your question is incomplete.